# href with a slide in picture

Tags: html, css

i have a slide in over an image as you can see here

http://jsfiddle.net/xt94eah2/4/

when you hover over the example image you get a caption. But, how do i put a link in it?

So only when you hover and you see the grey part with says with some more info that you can then click the image and it goes to a link for example w3schools.

i have the code here

```
    <div class="image revealUpFull">
        <img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/8/8NNM3Tc.png" width="150px" height="150px" />
        <span class="title">Caption <br / ><br / > with some more info</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the CSS

```
div.container {
    margin: 50px auto;
    width: 675px;
}

div.image {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 260px;
    height: 195px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;

    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;

    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all .3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease-out;
    transition: all .3s ease-out;
}

span.title {
    width: 260px;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(30,30,30,0.9);
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 0 4px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: white;
    font-family: "Lucida Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Arial, sans-serif;

    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all .3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease-out;
    transition: all .3s ease-out;

}
div.image.revealUpFull span { 
    height: 195px;
    width: 260px;
    bottom: -150px;
}

div.image.revealUpFull:hover img {
    top: -150px;
}

div.image.revealUpFull:hover span {
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

Comment: is there anything wrong by just adding the link in? `<span class="title"><a href="#">Caption <br / ><br / > with some more info</a></span>`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xt94eah2/5/ ?

Comment: @GCyrillus no because then you need to press a link i want that you can click anywhere on the grey area

Comment: @sdcr yes because then you need to press links and what i want is that i can just press the grey area

Comment: @jdkfjldkl okay, so lay the link all over that span : http://jsfiddle.net/xt94eah2/8/ or turn the span into a link http://jsfiddle.net/xt94eah2/9/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you can do if I got it right for your question (You would like the whole slide in area to be clickable?). So you can make both `span` and `a` with full width and height of the area.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/xt94eah2/7/

```
div.image.revealUpFull span {
    height: 141px;
    width: 150px;
    bottom: -120px;
    display: block;
}
div.image.revealUpFull span a {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
}
```

There are a few corrections for the markup.

1. The last `</div>` is mis-matched.
2. The inline `<img src="" width="150px" height="150px" />` is wrong, it should be `width="150" height="150"` without `px`.

Comment: hi but then is it possible that hte words are not underlined?

Comment: of course, just add `text-decoration: none;` into the CSS

Comment: hi it kinda works now but for some reason my web page where the style sheet is is weird and it like it doesnt have a style anymore
when you click the picture here on this link http://sandergouman.nl/index.html#work you see what the problem is
it should look like this http://i61.tinypic.com/2gxl76f.png

Comment: @jdkfjldkl yep sounds good, let me know if you need further advices, and looks like you're new to here, make sure to check out http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: hi it kinda works now but for some reason my web page where the style sheet is is weird and it like it doesnt have a style anymore
when you click the picture here on this link http://sandergouman.nl/index.html#work you see what the problem is
it should look like this http://i61.tinypic.com/2gxl76f.png

Comment: @jdkfjldkl this is what you need `div.image.revealUpFull span {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  bottom: -150px;
  display: block;
}`

Comment: do you maybe have a jsfiddle for that? still learning so i dont really know where to place it

Comment: @jdkfjldkl you can search for `div.image.revealUpFull span` in your style.css and replace the rules inside with the code in above comment

Comment: hi when i do that the site is still messed up

Comment: @jdkfjldkl i can see it's be applied, the box shows there nicely, I believe this question is complete. you can open a new post for other questions you have.